# Assigning array after permuting

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, indexing

I wish to assign my `labels` array after permuting it. I am using a code similar to below.

```
np.random.seed(42)
labels = np.zeros((10,1),dtype=int)
idx = np.random.permutation(len(labels))
labels[idx][1:5] = np.random.randint(0,10,(4,1))
```

However, as can be see below the labels are still zero, and nothing has been assigned. I can only imagine that the labels[idx] part creates a copy and thats what's being assigned to. How do I circumvent this?

```
labels
>>> array([[0],
       [0],
       [0],
       [0],
       [0],
       [0],
       [0],
       [0],
       [0],
       [0]])
```

The required output was this:

```
for i,j in enumerate(idx2):
    labels[idx[j]] = a[i]

labels  
>>> array([[7],
   [2],
   [0],
   [0],
   [0],
   [6],
   [0],
   [4],
   [0],
   [0]])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following snippet answered my question:

```
idx2 = np.argsort(idx)
labels[1:5] = a

labels[idx2]
```

The key was to find the mapping from the permutation back to the original permutation. Which is what `np.argsort(idx)` did.

Comment: I couldn't figure out why you were using the double random - of index and value.

Comment: If the idx does the random permutation, the argsort part puts it back in the normal order. i.e. the mapping back to the original order. check it out with a small sample eg. `np.random.permutation(5)`

Answer (score 1):

```
In [207]: idx
Out[207]: array([5, 8, 3, 7, 9, 1, 6, 0, 4, 2])
In [208]: x=np.random.randint(0,10,(10,1))
In [209]: x
Out[209]: 
array([[5],
       [7],
       [4],
       [4],
       [9],
       [6],
       [2],
       [1],
       [9],
       [9]])
In [210]: labels[idx]=x
In [211]: labels
Out[211]: 
array([[1],
       [6],
       [9],
       [4],
       [9],
       [5],
       [2],
       [4],
       [7],
       [9]])
```

When using an index like `idx`, you have to do

```
 labels[idx] = ...
```

Doing `labels[idx][:5] = ....` does not work, because `labels[idx]` by itself creates a copy.

`labels[:5][idx[:5]] = ...` should work, because `[:5]` creates a view.

Correction:

```
labels[:5][np.random.randint(0,5,5)]=np.arange(5)[:,None]
```

If necessary I'd suggest reviewing documentation on views vs copies, and basic vs advanced indexing.

Comment: 'IndexError: index 7 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 5': 
you are assuming that `idx[:5]` would be constrained to length 5, which its not. `labels` has a length of ten.

Comment: Yes, I didn't test the `idx[:5]` part.  The point I was trying to make is that slicing first will work.

Comment: @hpaulj your answers are always very precise and documented, but why don't you follow pep8?

Comment: Cause this isn't CodeReview? :)  Or I haven't read pep8 in quite sometime.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean this?

```
labels = np.zeros((10,1),dtype=int)
idx = np.random.permutation(len(labels))
pool = np.random.randint(0,10,(4,1))
for i in range(4):
    labels[i] = pool[i]
print labels
```

Comment: idx is a random permutation of length 10.  

labels[idx] returns labels, but with the order changed (i.e., instead of index 0,1,2,3..., it is now 7,3,9,1...)

But labels is nothing but zeroes to start.  So what are you hoping to get by changing the indexing?  Help me understand.

Comment: The labels are from a machine learning problem where the data is mixed with `idx`. So at the end of it I need the labels in their originally format. My example is a huge simplification of the actual problem.

Comment: Please update your question with an example of what you are looking to obtain in 'labels' after the assignment has been finished.